# JBoss 5.1 binds to host address while run in vserver with -b <guest address>

Tags: jboss, networking, jboss5.x

while starting JBoss 5.1.0.GA in virtual server machine on Debian (linux-VServer technology) I get the following error:

`ERROR [org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelController] (main) Error installing to Start: name=jboss.remoting:protocol=rmi,service=JMXConnectorServer state=Create mode=Manual requiredState=Installed
java.io.IOException: Cannot bind to URL [rmi://10.1.2.11:1090/jmxconnector]: javax.naming.NoPermissionException [Root exception is java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is:
        java.rmi.AccessException: Registry.Registry.bind disallowed; origin /AA.BB.CC.DD is non-local host]`

where AA.BB.CC.DD is host machine name, 10.1.2.11 is vserver guest with JBoss and JBoss is started with -b 10.1.2.11 (I also tried -Djboss.bind.address=10.1.2.11 - the same result).

10.1.2.11 is bound to dummy2 interface on host (serving 10.1.2.1 network).

The root exception is strange - why JBoss wants to bind to host address AA.BB.CC.DD? There were no problems with 4.2.3.GA on the same machine, also started with -b 10.1.2.11.

It starts correctly when no params present - binds to localhost and everything is ok, but it MUST be bound to 10.1.2.11 to be visible by Apache on another vserver guest, acting as proxy.

I thought that it can be fixed by setting net.ipv4.conf.all.promote_secondaries=1 via sysctl (was 0) but it didn't help much.

Has anyone had such problem?

Regards,
bart

Answer (score 0):

Could you confirm if The port //10.1.2.11:1090/ isn't being used by another process (even a zombie one : P)?

There was a problem similar at [JbossJIRA](https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/JBAS-3885) a couple of years ago... But i though it was already fixed.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that no 10.1.2.11:1090 is listed in netstat -an on guest system after stopping JBoss, on host there is also no activity reported on this port. The problem looks similar to JIRA's one.

Comment: Did you discover what was causing the issue Bart? : )

Comment: No, I didn't :( Since this is test server and application runs correctly on it there were no pressure to investigate the problem. Changing BindAddress in .../deploy/jmx-remoting.sar/META-INF/jboss-service.xml has no effect.

Comment: Finally I had some time to check JBoss 6 and it seems to work ok in the same environment (the same machine in fact).